# Problem finding a proper JPA mapping for a class hierarchy containing an interface

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, interface

I have given a complicated class hierarchy I have to find a JPA mapping for. I stripped the core problem down to the simplest case:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class A extends TimestampedEntity<Long> {

    /* How to map this interface? */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a") // this does not work in JPA
    private List<Special> specials;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class B extends A {}

@Entity
public class C extends A {}

Interface Special {
    void setA(A a);
    A getA();
}

@Entity
public class SpecialB extends B implements Special {
    @ManyToOne
    private A a;
    // getter, setter, ...
}

@Entity
public class SpecialC extends C implements Special {
    @ManyToOne
    private A a;
    // getter, setter, ...
}
```

According to many posts here addressing the problem JPA cannot map interfaces, the common solution is to squeeze an abstract class in between the interface and it's implementing classes and map the abstract class instead of the interface. This is obviously not possible here because the inheritance hierarchy is deeper and the classes implementing `Special` are already inheriting.

What is the common approach to solve this? The only way I can think of is to get rid of the interface and clutter the code with `instanceof` wherever an instance of `Special` is required, what is not desirable. Can someone with more experience in JPA mapping point out a better solution?

(Java EE 8, Wildfly 12, JPA 2.2, Persistence Provider Hibernate 5.1.10)

Comment: How about having dedicated properties for `List<B>` and `List<C>` in `A` and add them in a common `List<Special>` on `@PostLoad` or in the getter of `List<Special>` ?

Comment: I assume you mean `List<SpecialB>` and `List<SpecialC>` in `A`, mapped to the concrete classes and combine them to a common `List<Special>` on `@PostLoad`? A bit ugly, as I have a whole bunch of `Special` classes, but sounds doable. Might try that, thanks.

Comment: You have configured a @OneToMany relationship between A and, let's say, SpecialB and both classes are mapped to the same table. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yeah, it's not very elegant but you could keep the SpecialA/B properties private (no getters/setters) and this "technically conditioned burden" would at least be hidden.

Comment: @EugenCovaci The domain model was there first, and it makes sense, the mapping of the entire hierarchy to a single table might make sense or not, but if I map to joined tables the problem with the interface won't disappear, so it's irrelevant in this context.

Comment: @Meini A problem with your solution is that `specials` cannot  be used in JQL queries.

Comment: Since you have a single table, all @XToX relationships inside inheritance tree makes no sense to me.

Comment: @EugenCovaci You suggest I don't need the entity relationship mappings when using single table inheritance strategy? You're sure? Because the spec says otherwise:
"If there is an association between two entities, one of the following relationship modeling annotations must be applied to the corresponding persistent property or field of the referencing entity: OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToOne, ManyToMany." (JSR 338, JPA 2.2 Page 44)

Comment: Association doesn't mean inheritance.

Comment: @EugenCovaci Why does any ´@XToX´ makes no sense to you if all entities are inside the same inheritance tree? This is pretty usual in a composite pattern, no matter if they are in the same or in different tables. In this example there is both, association and inheritance.

Comment: @Meini If it is pretty usual, can you point me an official example with inheritance single table and association within the inheritance tree? Suppose you have a single table in a database. Does make sense to talk about association?

Comment: @EugenCovaci Consider a simple tree consisting of parent-child-relationships of the same entity `A` with lets say just the properties `@ManyToOne A parent` and `@OneToMany List<A> children`. That means you have all records in the same table with columns `ID` and `PARENT_ID`. And now consider there is an Entity `B` extending `A`, then you have an additional column `DTYPE` and thats it: the same inheritance tree and associations between them.

Comment: @Meini Wrong example, you suppose A has an association to himself (which requires a parent_pk field foreign key to, let's say, pk). This is not the general case, and certainly not the OP case.

Comment: Have you tried using Cascade? https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/

Comment: @EugenCovaci This is not wrong, this is exactly OP case. `A` has an association to subclasses of itself, which are mapped to the same table. And yes, there has to be a foreign key column like `PARENT_ID` in order to use it in a `@JoinColumn`, otherwise there wouldn't be any `@OneToMany`/`@ManyToOne` possible just like there has to be a `@DiscriminatorColumn`/`@DiscriminatorValue` like `DTYPE` to map the subclasses. I suppose these both are just omitted in OP's example because they're totally irrelevant for the actual question.

Comment: As I said in the OP "I stripped the core problem down to the simplest case" to make my problem as clear as possible. In reality the domain model is much more complicated, there are more annotations of various kinds, etc. But this is not relevant to my question so I omitted it all.